# How to intercept the navigation between Struts 2 Actions?

Tags: struts2, struts, action, intercept

I´m using Struts 2. Is it possible to identify and intercept when a user navigates do another Action?

I need to identify if the user is going to an Action different then the one he is currently on.

Answer (score 1):

It's easy.  Just use Struts 2 interceptor.

```java
public class TestInterceptor extends AbstractInterceptor {

    public String intercept(ActionInvocation invocation) throws Exception {
        // Do checking here, get user from session or from parameter is OK.
        // Example:
        // string returned below will be redirected to result of Struts 2 action
        String roleName = user.getRole().getName();
        if ("admin".equals(roleName) {
            return "admin";
        } else if("user".equals(roleName)) {
            return "user";
        }

        // This means if roleName is not admin or user, the action will be invoked
        return invocation.invoke();
    }

}
```

Then just add above interceptor in *struts.xml* configuration. I think this is what you want, right?  I always use this interceptor.

See http://struts.apache.org/2.x/docs/interceptors.html or http://www.benmccann.com/blog/struts-2-tutorial-interceptors/ for the samples.